# How to access the shared folder between two computers running ubuntu

Tags: samba

I have to computers running Ubuntu and I want to share files between those computer. these computers are already connected through a cross cable and sharing internet connection using firestarter. Both computers have samba installed.

In Desktop computer I have a shared folder How do I access it on the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

Under Places, Connect to Server... Set Service type to Windows share, and fill in the details.

**Option 2**

In Nautilus, press CTRL-L, type `smb://serverip/`, e.g. `smb://192.168.0.2`, and press Enter.

Comment: when I do this, I see a folder written printer on it (I dont have any printer in the network). how do I change to the directory which is in ~/Desktop

Comment: If you have given the shared folder a share name then it should be accessible using, e.g. smb://serverip/sharename

Comment: Why do I need to use Samba/WindowsShare to connect two Linux computers?

Comment: Good question feeela. The choice of SSH are a much better solution for most Ubuntu-users (also in Files/Connect to server...). SSH are more modern and secure than the old and clunky Windows SMB-protocoll.

Comment: If SSH server is installed then this would indeed be the easiest solution. In this case, you can use ssh://serverip/.